# PHP / Google Sheets API : Uncaught Google\Service\Exception Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"0\" at 'data.values[0]

Tags: php, google-sheets-api

I'm using PHP to read/write data in a Google Sheet but I'm getting the error Uncaught Google\Service\Exception Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "0" at 'data.values[0].

I have seen many posts with the same error but I can't figure out what's wrong with my payload. The script that I'm using is parsing more than 1000 lines successfully but suddenly it breaks on one particular line and I don't see why.

Here is the PHP part:

```
$updateRow = [$articles[$key]["id"],$articles[$key]["language"],$articles[$key]["rawurl"],$articles[$key]["publishdate"],$articles[$key]["modifieddate"],$articles[$key]["internal_title"],$articles[$key]["internal_desc"],$articles[$key]["seo_title"],$articles[$key]["seo_desc"],$articles[$key]["product"],$articles[$key]["score"],$articles[$key]["tags"],$articles[$key]["categories"],$articles[$key]["ads"]];
$rows = [$updateRow];
$valueRange = new \Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange();
$valueRange->setValues($rows);
$range = 'Blog_Metadata!A'.$position; 
$options = ['valueInputOption' => 'USER_ENTERED'];
output($valueRange);
output($options);
$service->spreadsheets_values->update($spreadsheetId, $range, $valueRange, $options);
```

This works fine for all the other entries. Let's now get into the details of the payload.

$article[$key] contains the following:

```
Array
(
[id] => 2187
[rawurl] => nl%2Froadtrip%2Frondreis-italie%2Fcomo-meer
[permalink] => nl/roadtrip/rondreis-italie/como-meer
[publishdate] => 1519675325
[modifieddate] => 1519675325
[language] => nl
[translations] => Array
    (
        [fr] => 2128
        [nl] => 2187
        [en] => 2177
        [es] => 
        [de] => 
        [it] => 
    )

[translations_url] => Array
    (
        [fr] => fr%2Fcircuits%2Fcircuit-italie%2Flac-de-come%2F
        [nl] => nl%2Froadtrip%2Frondreis-italie%2Fcomo-meer%2F
        [en] => en%2Froadtrips%2Froadtrip-italy%2Flake-como-visit%2F
        [es] => 
        [de] => 
        [it] => 
    )

[ads] => https://www.booking.com/searchresults.nl.html?ss=como&aid=324758
[internal_title] => Comomeer
[internal_desc] => Een echt concentraat van Italië met prachtige landschappen, bioscoopstukken, jetset, geschiedenis en goede (ijs)ballen.
[seo_title] => Comomeer - Reisverhaal (activiteiten, foto' s,...)
[seo_desc] => Een echt concentraat van Italië met prachtige landschappen, bioscoopstukken, jetset, geschiedenis en goede (ijs)ballen.
[product] => 
[score] => 
[tags] => 
[categories] => rondreis-italie
[thumbnail] => https://images.laurentwillen.be/sites/21/2018/02/lac-de-come-top-300x94.jpg
[thumbnail_large] => https://images.laurentwillen.be/sites/21/2018/02/lac-de-come-top-1400x438.jpg
[thumbnail_max] => https://images.laurentwillen.be/sites/21/2018/02/lac-de-come-top-1900x594.jpg
)
```

Empty fields are very common, it's not specific to this one.

The content of $updateRow is:

```
Array
(
[0] => 2187
[1] => nl
[2] => nl%2Froadtrip%2Frondreis-italie%2Fcomo-meer
[3] => 1519675325
[4] => 1519675325
[5] => Comomeer
[6] => Een echt concentraat van Italië met prachtige landschappen, bioscoopstukken, jetset, geschiedenis en goede (ijs)ballen.
[7] => Comomeer - Reisverhaal (activiteiten, foto' s,...)
[8] => Een echt concentraat van Italië met prachtige landschappen, bioscoopstukken, jetset, geschiedenis en goede (ijs)ballen.
[9] => 
[10] => 
[11] => 
[12] => rondreis-italie
[13] => https://www.booking.com/searchresults.nl.html?ss=como&aid=324758
)
```

the content is $valueRange is:

```
Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange Object
(
[collection_key:protected] => values
[majorDimension] => 
[range] => 
[values] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 2187
                [1] => nl
                [2] => nl%2Froadtrip%2Frondreis-italie%2Fcomo-meer
                [3] => 1519675325
                [4] => 1519675325
                [5] => Comomeer
                [6] => Een echt concentraat van Italië met prachtige landschappen, bioscoopstukken, jetset, geschiedenis en goede (ijs)ballen.
                [7] => Comomeer - Reisverhaal (activiteiten, foto' s,...)
                [8] => Een echt concentraat van Italië met prachtige landschappen, bioscoopstukken, jetset, geschiedenis en goede (ijs)ballen.
                [9] => 
                [10] => 
                [11] => 
                [12] => rondreis-italie
                [13] => https://www.booking.com/searchresults.nl.html?ss=como&aid=324758
            )

    )

[internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[modelData:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[processed:protected] => Array
    (
    )

)
```

The JSON payload looks fine to me. I have compared it with payloads that worked but I see no difference. I sometimes have empty entries and it works. For some reason, quotes are not correctly rendered here but I have entries with quotes before this one and everything works well.

Do you see anything that would explain why my scripts breaks at that specific point?

thanks

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand the reason for your current issue, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direct solution to your current issue, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your showing sample values, I guessed that the null value might be the reason for your current issue of `Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"0\" at 'data.values[0]`. If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
$rows = [$updateRow];
```

#### To:

```
$rows = [array_map(function($e) {
  return (is_null($e)) ? "" : $e;
},$updateRow)];
```

or, I thought that this might be able to be also used.

```
$rows = [array_map('strval', $updateRow)];
```

- By this modification, the null value is converted to `""`.
- In the case of `$rows = [array_map('strval', $updateRow)];`, I thought that the number values are put as the number by `USER_ENTERED`.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution works but I don't know why. The script already parsed more than 1000 entries with empty values so I assumed that empty values were not the problem but you are right, it now works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Laurent Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I think that the null value can be used for "Method: spreadsheets.values.update". For example, when the null value is used with ["Try this method"](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update), you can confirm that the request can be worked. From this situation, I'm that the reason for this issue might be due to the library of googleapis for PHP. But, I'm not sure whether this is the current specification or a bug. I apologize for this.